# Can we run both ojdbc5 & ojdbc14 in same jboss instance

Tags: oracle, jdbc

We are facing one scenario where our application is hosted on the shared JBOSS server where other application are using oracle 11g and require to use 'ojdbc14.jar'

Where in our application DB is upgraded to 12c and we need to use 'ojdbc5.jar'.

Now issue is it conflicting and we need a solution to have both the jars and still not impact other application.

For now DBA helped us with sqlnet.ora but they are still recommending to upgrade the drivers.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc5.jar **are not versions of the driver**, they specify the Java version (Java 1.4 and Java 5). The latest Oracle JDBC driver (12.10.2) can also connect to Oracle 11g, so there is no need to use different versions.

Comment: Refer to this FAQ for more details on JDBC driver and JDK version it is compatible with. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03